# Choosing between two different professors to advise my undergrad thesis

Tags: publications, advisor, computer-science, professorship, research-undergraduate

I am a computer science undergrad student (second degree student, on the road to a PhD). I am in a bit of a pickle. I came up with a feasible research idea for my thesis and I want to work on it mostly independently however, I never published before so I want to increase my chances by getting some guidance.
There are two professors at my school who work in my domain. But there are two potential problems:

1. The professor who's work most closely relates to my research interests said he will not be advising undergrad students until the Spring. I just finished up at another research lab. I discovered that a lot of people are interested in this specific topic I am researching, and it's applications (I am focusing on an application of it). I would rather get started sooner than later. **TLDR;** cited ~900 times, publishes in the specific domains I am interested in, assistant professor, graduated 10 years ago
2. The other professor said he will advise me starting now but, he publishes mostly in robotics journals. Now, the research I am doing is robotics related, but it is more machine learning related. I would want to publish in conferences or journals more related to ML than a pure robotics journal. if you're not in CS, you may ignore this part: He mostly publishes in The International Journal of Robotics Research, while I am aiming for JIPC, Artificial Intelligence, NeurIPS, and The Journal of Machine Learning Research for this paper. The other professor has published in these ~8 times. This professor has published in JIPC and AAAI once or twice. **TLDR;** cited ~ 5000 times, publishes in mostly one domain, does not publish in conferences I'd like to see my work in often, but still publishes in what looks like reputable places, associate professor, graduated <10 years ago

I am not sure what would be more beneficial. I don't have the opportunity to work under a super famous professor, so it looks like another way to get my research out there would be publishing in more "popular" journals.

- Is it worth the wait to work with the other professor in the Spring? I was thinking I could tell him my topic now, ask if he would at least confirm it is feasible, and write up a white paper this fall in preparation for Spring.
- Or, should I get started because this is a very hot subject and I shouldn't let months of valuable research time get by?
- should I try to get a professor who is more well known at a different uni to advise me?

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing in your question suggests that you want an advisor with the most cachet in the field, so that your results (which you do not have yet) will have the most visibility. That would suggest waiting for the spring. If so, yes do the white paper and wait.

But often what you need an advisor for is advice — that is, help and guidance doing the actual work (which you have not done yet). The second professor might be really good at that even though the field isn't his primary interest.

Comment: very true. if I want to attempt to publish in a certain conference where I think my work will be applicable, is it appropriate to ask them ? How does that typically work

Comment: @user129686 I'm not familiar with cs conferences. You could consult someone who has submitted to that conference. In general, I think about where to publish something when the work is finished, or nearly so.